# Get Directory contents but dont show directory

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess

I have Linux hosting and I want to get files by its specified URL only because these files are only for registered users. But when I am accessing its directory URL all files are showing up.

Example: www.site.com/files             (This should redirect to home page)

Example: www.site.com/files/filename.zip ( This should be able to download file)

I also tried a .htaccess modrewite but with files directory it was also not showing the file.

Any Idea, How to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lame workaround, nevertheless; you could just include a empty `index` file in the directory.

Also you could add this line in your `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf` file:

```
IndexIgnore *
```

Comment: Oh! I am really an idiot, I didnt think about this.. He he :D

Answer (score 2):

Indexing:

1. Disable directory indexing

Rewrite:

1. Condition: requested file is not a file (a directory is not a file)
2. Rule: Redirect to document root

`Options -Indexes`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteRule ^ / [R]`

Answer (score 1):

Change directory permissions to 711.  You will say: `chmod 711 files` where `files` is the directory containing your files.  You can also add a file named `index.html` in the directory `files` that will be displayed by default when someone tried to access `www.site.com/files`.

Answer (score 1):

To turn off apache’s automatically-generated directory listings, add

```
Options -Indexes
```

to `.htaccess`. See the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options) for `Options` more information. See the documentation for Apache’s [`mod_autoindex` module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html) to customize the display of the index page.

Answer (score 0):

Just put an `index.php` in the folder in question, just containing:

```
<?php

header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/');
die;
```

And ditch the `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the direct downloadlink with a download.php with something like this:

```
<?php
$downloadfile = "files/filename.zip";
$filename = "filename.zip";
$filesize = filesize($downloadfile);

header("Content-Type: application/zip"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$filename'"); 
header("Content-Length: $filesize");

readfile($downloadfile);
exit;
?>
```

You can see that we send a header with the the .zip file in the header. It will download the file without opening the folder-view.

Hope it will help you.